# Converting from ejs to html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, passport.js

So i have been following this tutorial that uses ejs. But i am not very familiar with ejs and would therefore like to understand how i can convert the server.js from ejs to html. The code is as shown:

```
app.set('view-engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(flash())
app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}))
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
app.use(methodOverride('_method'))

app.get('/', checkAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  res.render('index.ejs', { name: req.user.name })
})

app.get('/login', checkNotAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  res.render('login.ejs')
})

app.post('/login', checkNotAuthenticated, passport.authenticate('local', {
  successRedirect: '/',
  failureRedirect: '/login',
  failureFlash: true
}))

app.get('/register', checkNotAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  res.render('register.ejs')
})


app.listen(3000)
```

Note that the login, index and register files are also ejs files and not html. I have tried to change their names to html and switched ejs for html in the code above, but the html cannot find the files when that they should be redirected to when pressing the submit buttons. For instance, the register button should direct you back to the login page, and the login page should proceed to index. But none of it has worked.

Any input to how i can change from ejs to html?

Comment: Why do you need to convert it to EJS

Comment: No, i want to convert it from ejs to html, as i am more familiar with ejs and would rather keep it structured that way

Comment: This code that you've submitted is normal JavaScript through Node, with the ExpressJS router. This is backend server code, not a ejs or html file.

Answer (score 1):

`render` is designed to inject data into a template and then return the result. It works by looking up files based on the name you pass it and the selected view engine.

HTML files aren't templates though, so you shouldn't be using them with `render` in the first place.

If you want to serve static files, then use [the `static` module](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) instead of creating explicit routes.

However, you don't need to be familiar with EJS to use it since it is nothing more than HTML with special rules for what happens between `<%` and `%>`. Since you can't use   `<%` and `%>` in HTML in the first place, you are just write plain HTML in your EJS files.

Comment: So basically what you suggest is that i remove the render files, change the names from ejs to html and it should be working?

Comment: No, because you'd still need to setup the static module multiple times for different routes with different levels of auth. What I'm suggesting is to just stop worrying about having HTML files with `.ejs` on the end of the names.

Comment: It's just because i'd rather use html over ejs for my own preference, hence why i am asking for advice regarding to the coding.